# Scaling a figure axis in Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, imshow

I'm currently trying to visualize a matrix in Python using Matplotlib, however, the problem is that the number of columns, is much greater than the number of rows, so when i visualize it, the y-axis becomes small, as seen on the following figure. [image]

The matrix is a pandas DataFrame with 23 rows and 1880 columns. I've tried to visualize it with `imshow()` and `matshow`, but both methods scales the picture awkwardly. I've also attempted `tight_layout()` but it doesn't really change anything.

Is there anything I can do to scale the plot?

Here is the code i'm using for plotting:

```
plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
plt.imshow(df.drop(["column2"], axis=1).transpose(), cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest')
plt.savefig("Test.pdf")
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code you are using for the plot?

Comment: I've added the code snippet above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good aspect ratio using the [`pcolor`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor.html) function. Your code snippet would become:

```
plt.pcolor(df.drop(["column2"], axis=1).transpose(), cmap='hot')
plt.savefig("Test.pdf")
```

Unfortunately, the interpolation keyword is not supported and I don't know if you need it. This is the result I obtain with some random data:
[image: visualization with good aspect ratio]

Answer (score 1):

[imshow](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) knows an `aspect` keyword argument which you can set to `auto` to do this:

```
plt.imshow(... , aspect='auto')
```